# vb combobox list dropdown - displayall items beginning with a letter

Tags: vb.net, combobox, alphabetical

In VB, ComboBox, with DropDownStyle property set to DropDownList:

If I have a long list of items (lets say 100+) in alphabetical order, when the user types a letter, is there a way to make ALL the words beginning with the letter visible in the dropdown list, instead of displaying just the FIRST word beginning with that letter at the bottom of the dropdown.  Or put another way, if the user types a letter, have ALL the words beginning with that letter display in the dropdown, starting at the top of the dropdown.

Comment: Look at the AutoCompleteXXX properties of the ComboBox.

Comment: Thanks.  As best as I can discover, if I set AutoCompleteMode to Suggest, and AutoCompleteSource to ListItems, it comes close to what I want.  The user has to type two letters for the dropdown to respond correctly, not one.